# Why is my remove event listener not working?

Tags: javascript

I am making a messaging system and I added file uploading. My javascript functions adds event listeners on click and they stack, but my remove Event listener isn't working. My code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function bro() {
    document.querySelector('#file').removeEventListener('change',(e)=>{console.log('removed listener')}, true);
    document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      var file = this.files[0];

      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("file", file);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
      var fullurl = '../backend/sendvideosandimages.php?id=' + group_id;
        xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (this.status == 200) {
          };
      };
      xhr.send(fd);
    }, true);
    }
    </script>
```

The input :

```
<input type="file" id="file" onclick="bro()"name="file" value="FILE UPLOAD" style="opacity: 0;z-index: 100000; bottom: 17.5px; position: fixed; right: 10px;">
```

Please help

My new code still doesn't work :

````
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function bro() {
      document.querySelector('#file').removeEventListener('change',Myhandlerfunction, true);
      document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', Myhandlerfunction, true);
      function Myhandlerfunction() {
          var file = this.files[0];

          var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("file", file);
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var group_id = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
          var fullurl = '../backend/sendvideosandimages.php?id=' + group_id;
            xhr.open('POST', fullurl, true);
            xhr.onload = function() {
              if (this.status == 200) {
              };
          };
          xhr.send(fd);
      }
    }
    </script>
``` It adds the event listener but doesn't remove it
````

Comment: you must remove exactly the same that you add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code will not call the function handler you provide:

```js
    document.querySelector('#file').removeEventListener('change',(e)=>{console.log('removed listener')}, true);
```

The way `removeEventListener` works is that ... Lets say you have function `myHandlerFunction()` defined and you register it as an event listener like so:

```js
var myHandlerFunction = (e) => {console.log('removed listener')};
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', myHandlerFunction, true);
```

At a later point of time, you can remove the event listener like so:

```js
document.querySelector('#file').removeEventListener('change', myHandlerFunction, true);
```

After which, when such an event is raised it will no longer call your handler function. You may read more about [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

**EDIT:**
As discussed in the comments, OP was defining the function handler in the scope of the function `bro()` that registered it. Multiple calls to the function `bro()` was causing to add a new event handler to the event without removing the old one. Defining the function handler outside the scope of the function `bro()` allowed removal of the handler.

Comment: It still isn't calling it

Comment: Why are you removing `Myhandlerfunction` before adding it?

Comment: It calls the addevent listener, but doesn't add the remove listener. I want the code to remove the listener because the listeners stack

Comment: Could you define the `Myhandlerfunction` outside the scope of `bro()` and try?

Answer (score 0):

when you use addEventListener & removeEventListener you need to define your functions by names , dont use a anonymous functions

for example :

```
element.addEventListener('change', function x(e){
  console.log('event listener');
});

element.removeEventListener('change', x);
```